# Using UIPopoverController with UIImagePickerController for connect to Ipad photo gallery

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I create an application and have "Gallery" button, I want to when push that button I can see all image in Ipad photo gallery. My code is here:

```
- (IBAction)btGallery:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    if(popoverController == nil)
    {
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    }
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

But when I push that button, I cant see anything ... please help me!

Comment: is the popover is displaying ?

Comment: what u mean?, nothing is happen :(

Comment: put a break point on the method and check whether it's entering on the method, if not check the outlets are connected

Comment: no, i put NSLog under popoverController and it work, but i can see anything is happen on simulator :((

Answer (score 2):

I have done it programmatically and its working for me.
Add this code in your button method

Make sure you change the names of the ivars

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.picker.delegate = self;

self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.picker];

[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 350)
                                   inView:self.view
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                 animated:YES];}
```

This should work for you please notify if you cannot.